# RegExp cut word(s) from - to

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression which returns a string which is between two other.

Strings can be:

> 1. Select FROM item.ui where blah blah blah...
> 2. Select FROM item.ui(x,y) AND blah blah...
> 3. Select FROM item AND blah blah...

Would return:

> 1. item.ui
> 2. item.ui
> 3. item

```js
var value = "Select FROM item.ui where blah blah blah"
var re = /(?<=FROM ).*(?= (\s|[(]))/g;
var test = value.match(re);
console.log(test)
```

Comment: The regex  should be: `FROM (.*?)[\s(]`, but in your request it is not clear what is the conditions to end the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(?<=FROM\s)([^\s]+)` here is an example:

```js
let arr = ["Select FROM item.ui where blah blah blah...",
  "Select FROM item.ui(x,y) AND blah blah...",
  "Select FROM item AND blah blah..."
]

arr = arr.map(v => v.match(/(?<=FROM\s)([^\s]+)/)[0]);

console.log(arr);
```

`[^\s]` will match any character that isn't a whitespace, you can extend this list with other characters that you want to break on.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to find something starting with FROM, then a space, then the thing you want to find, then another space, and the thing you want to find can't have a space in it.

```js
var value = "Select FROM item.ui where blah blah blah"
var re = /FROM (\S+) .*/;
console.log(value.match(re)[1])
```